# How do I copy an already existing field in manage display?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a field (entity reference) that is used to provide a link to another node. I want to have it two times in my "manage display" settings page, it's for redundancy. I don't want to create a new field, i just want a duplicate in the view mode. Is that possible? Maybe it's just hidden in plain view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to printing out a variable twice is to use a custom template. e.g. copy node.tpl.php or node--contenttype.tpl.php and put the link in there twice.

Don't forget to clear caches to see your changes.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would use would be to use a custom php snippet in a block to pull the field value out of $node and to format the field. I would then place the block in a region of the page where I needed it.

`<?php`

if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {

$node = node_load(arg(1));

if (isset($node->field_node_reference['und'])) {

```
foreach ($node->field_node_reference['und'] as $other_node) {
  $link = '/node/' . $other_node['node']->nid;
  $title = $other_node['node']->title;
  print (l( $title, $link));
}
```

}

} ?>

This would be the core code for a node reference field. You should pretty it up to format your display, but this gets the information on your page a second time.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to follow the pattern that gets people to validate an email address by entering it twice? The end goal is not just to have the element twice in the administration screens?

If the goal is to get people to type out a field response twice, then it is appropriate to have the field twice as you need 2x responses for the validation - to compare then to make sure they are the same. Having 2 instances of a field without 2 corresponding values is a logical problem - which instance would you want the to be submitted back to the server?

It is possible to use javascript/jquery to clone the html form element and then check that it is the same without submitting the second value. Try [http://api.jquery.com/clone/](http://api.jquery.com/clone/%20jQuery%20Clone) and compare the result on submit.

Comment: Hm, i guess you misunderstood my Q or i was not very clear. It's not a form field, i just need a copy of a field (containing a link) to put in some other place in the node view. Like having a link to some other content under the title (for example) and having the same link positioned on bottom of the node (for example).

Comment: In that case you need to create a custom template. e.g.  copy node.tpl.php to node--contentype.tpl.php and put the link you want added in there twice. Don't forget to  clear caches to see your changes.

Comment: It worked with a custom template. Thanks & if you make your comment an answer i could vote it up and select it as accepted.